# Why my html code also display when i send email?

Tags: email, sendmail, send, sendmessage

hi dear this is my code to send email
my message code is this

```
$to = $email;
$subject = "Activation";
$message = "Your activation key is this " .$key.'<br>'.' click here to activate your acount. <a href="activation.php?key='.$key.'">here</a>';
$from = "riaz_qadeer90@yahoo.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
{
    echo "Check your email to activate your acount.";
}
```

The problem is this when i send email the whole message shown in my inbox with code. why it not show "Click" as an anchore.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mail isn't HTML format by default, so it's sending this as plain text.  See [Example #4 on the PHP page for `mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for sending HTML email.  You need to specify the content type for the message headers:

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Note the `.=` operator being used here.  You'd be *appending* this to your existing `$headers` value.  So you'll also want to make sure your existing header is terminated properly:

```
$headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Thanks to answer me, but now another problem is this mail has been sent but "Click Here" link is not clickable, please help me

Comment: @RiazKhan: What's the rendered HTML in the email? Is the anchor tag broken in some way?

Comment: @RiazKhan: Based on the information you posted in your "answer" (which should be an edit to the question), your anchor tag is essentially broken.  All the tag references is `activation.php`.  However, within the context of an email (which isn't a website), that link has no meaning.  You'll need to make it a fully-qualified URL so that the client (browser, email client, etc.) knows where to send the user.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check following things:-

1>message content properly it has enclosed with which inverted comma,either ' or ".
2>check your header and additional header information properly concatenate with (.) operator or not.
Most of the time problem arrives in second case.

**$headers .= 'To: abc, bcd' . "\r\n";**
**$headers .= 'From:xyz ' . "\r\n";**

Answer (score 0):

Because you **must** define the header of your e-mail as HTML.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Comment: Thanks to answer me, but now another problem is this mail has been sent but "Click Here" link is nor clickable please help me

Comment: Can you elaborate?  A link to another site (_especially_ a known bad site like w3schools) by itself isn't really considered an answer on Stack Overflow.